# leaflet minichars group argument

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, r-leaflet

I would like to ask,
Is there a group arguments for function from `(leaflet.minicharts)`? I am using function `addFlows` function and I am tryng to insert it into layer control, however since it doesnt have have `group` argument, I dont know how to Do so.

example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(spdep)
library(leaflet.minicharts)
library(tidyverse)


URL <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_DEU_1_sp.rds"
data <- readRDS(url(URL))
cns <- poly2nb(data)
cS <- nb2listw(cns)

# Plotting results
plot(data)
plot(cS, coordinates(data), add = T)

# Plotting in ggplot 
# Converting to data.frame
data_df <- data.frame(coordinates(data))
colnames(data_df) <- c("long", "lat")

n = length(attributes(cS$neighbours)$region.id)
DA = data.frame(
from = rep(1:n,sapply(cS$neighbours,length)),
to = unlist(cS$neighbours),
weight = unlist(cS$weights)
)
DA = cbind(DA, data_df[DA$from,], data_df[DA$to,])
colnames(DA)[4:7] = c("long","lat","long_to","lat_to")



# Plotting in leaflet
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner, group = "Toner") %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>% 
addPolygons(data=data, weight = 0.8, fill = F, color = "red") %>% 
addFlows(lng0 = DA$long, lat0 = DA$lat,lng1 = DA$long_to, lat1 = DA$lat_to, dir = 2, maxThickness= 0.85) %>% 
#addPolylines(data=DA, lng = DA$long_to, lat = DA$lat_to, weight = 0.85) %>% 
addLayersControl(
  baseGroups = c( "CartoDB.Positron (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
  options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
)
```

I would like to insert `addFlows` into lazer control so it can be shownoff and shown on.

Comment: `scnsn <- knn2nb(cns, row.names = NULL, sym = T)` does not run. Can you check if there is something wring with it?

Comment: My hope was that `addOpacitySlider()` in the leaflet.opacity package would work in this case. But it seems that it does not work with `addFlows()` although both functions can take `layerID`.

Comment: Sorry my bad -  that line is not needed, I edited the code now it runs. Yes I dont know to to account for `addFlows()` that is why I poster the question

Comment: You could directly ask the package author if you can control the addFlow layers. Perhaps askig the author to add group argument?

Comment: How Do I contact the author?

Comment: Check the front page of CRAN manual. You can find the information.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same